# Scrollbar in one div only

Tags: html, css

Say, for example, I have two `divs` like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        MY CONTENTS
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        MY OTHER CONTENTS
    </div>
</body>
```

The first `div` has the attributes `position:fixed;` and `width:100%;` in CSS, the other `div` is just a div with much content inside.

Ok, there is a scrollbar in the right side, as usual. But this scrollbar affects all of the `divs`. I want the scrollbar to only affect the second `div`, is possible?

I tried everything with `overflow:auto`, `overflow:hidden`, and `overflow:scroll` but I didn't reach my goal...

---

**EDIT**: Here my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/upcfp/

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle example? it is hard to guess what happening without working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem, I used this code:

```
body{
overflow: hidden;
}
#main{
overflow: scroll;
}
#maincontent{
height: 1500px;
}
```

I specified the height in content of #main and it just worked, thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#div2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

That will only put the scrollbars when needed.  To always display them use `overflow-y: scroll;`.  I had prefixed the second div's ID with `div` as you should not use only numbers for IDs or attributes in general.

The `#` signifies that the rule will apply to an element with the ID that follows the `#`.  If you wanted it applied to all `div` then you would use a class instead.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6EVtN/

Without seeing more code, the issue could be due to browser compatibility.  Example above was tested in Mozilla Firefox 13.0.1 and IE 8.

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j4uAM/

Comment: Oh yes, numbers was just for the example...
I tried what you said but it didn't work...

Comment: I tried in Safari, Chrome, Firefox, but the result is the same, your example in jsfiddle works, but in my website not

Comment: @AntonioPitasi I have updated my answer with another link based off of your code.  Check it out and let me know if you are able to see the scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like that?

[jsfiddle Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/5VaQP/1/)

I edited your jsfiddle and removed some of the not needed parts for your question:

[edited version of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upcfp/4/)

seems like there was a

```
</div>
```

missing in the #header, but is that what you wanted to get?

Comment: Yes, i don't want the scrollbar over the green div, i want the scrollbar in the blue div only

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/6AZvm/2/) what you had in mind?

This is a simple method. I have the header at the top, absolutely positioned, at a height of 100 pixels. Below that, I have the main content area, which has a height of 100%, a transparent top border of 100 pixels (so the content appears below the absolutely positioned header).

The `box-sizing` property in CSS allows us to fit the entire element into the width and height we specify, including padding and borders. So including the top border, the height of the main content is 100%, and the scrollbar appears only on the main content div.

The trick here, by the way, is setting the height of both `html` and `body` to 100%. This wouldn't work otherwise.

CSS:

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}
#header {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background:#c3c3c3;
    z-index:1;
}
#main {
    background: #eee;
    height:100%;
    border-top:100px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:auto;
}​
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/upcfp/5/) is your fiddle using my solution.

Comment: Exactly, but if I write `overflow:hidden` for body tag, the scrollbar disappear and I can't scroll the content
Though I wrote `overflow:auto` for the main div...

Comment: @AntonioPitasi: Adding `overflow:hidden` to the body tag doesn't do anything here.

Comment: overflow: hidden to the body tag does explicitely hide eventually shown scrollbars in the browser window as far as i know

Comment: @r3bel: Yes, it does, but I assume that he wants a frame-like layout on this page, so having `overflow:hidden;` won't make a difference since my solution only has a scrollbar on the main content div.

Answer (score -1):

This a perfect solution, but I don't know how to keep code format in stackoverflow:

```
<script>
$("#cart").bind("mousewheel", function(e){
var intElemScrollHeight = document.getElementById("cart").scrollHeight;
var intElemClientHeight = document.getElementById("cart").clientHeight;
if( intElemScrollHeight - $("#cart").scrollTop() === intElemClientHeight) {
    $(document).bind("mousewheel", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0 ) {
    if($("#cart").scrollTop() != 0) {
        $(document).unbind("mousewheel"); 
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}});
$("#cart").on("mouseleave", function(event) {
   $(document).unbind("mousewheel");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_