# Scrolling custom blocks via buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to create a div block that can be scrolled up and down. But I got stuck.

```
 <script>
    function scrollWin() {
      window.scrollBy(0, 100);
    }
    </script>
```

However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).

Comment: Unclear what you want. You want to scroll an element? Is the element's content scrollable? Or are you trying to position the element?

Comment: please provide a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use: [**`Element.scrollIntoView()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Example:

```
Element.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth",
  block: "center",
  inline: "center"
});
```

I've made a demo.

```js
(function() {
  var btnFirstSection = document.getElementById("btnFirstSection"),
    btnSecondSection = document.getElementById("btnSecondSection");

  btnFirstSection.onclick = btnSecondSection.onclick = function() {
    var target = this.dataset.target;
    document.getElementById(target).scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "center",
      inline: "center"
    });
  };
}());
```

```css
.buttons,
#scrollDiv,
#scrollDiv p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.buttons {
  background-color: #b2bbc8;
}

.buttons button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#scrollDiv {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#scrollDiv,
#scrollDiv p {
  border: #b2bbc8 solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="btnFirstSection" data-target="first" type="button">First Section</button>
  <button id="btnSecondSection" data-target="second" type="button">Second Section</button>
</div>
<div id="scrollDiv">
  <div id="first">
    <h1>First Section</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="second">
    <h1>Second Section</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is important to consider the [**browser compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
    background-color:#8cbfcf;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
#header{
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#70b0c3;
    position:fixed;
    box-shadow:#19343d 0px 1px 2px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    z-index:999;
    }
#accountinfo{
    position: absolute;
    right:10px;
    top: 0px;
    font-family: Happy Monkey, sans-serif;
    color:#EFF;
    text-shadow:#000 1px 1px 1px;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height: 60px;
    }
#blank{
     height:60px;
     width:100%;
    }
#main{
    height: 1500px;
    width:580px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:#70b0c3;
    box-shadow: #254C58 1px 0px;
    border: #3C7D91 1px double;
    border-bottom:0px;
    opacity:0.9;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 400px;
    }
#leftside{
    top: 80px;
    left: 160px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 230px;
    background-color: #70B0C3;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border: #3C7D91 1px double;
    position:fixed;
    box-shadow: #254C58 1px 1px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
#rightside{
    position:fixed;
    top:80px;
    right:160px;
    height:300px;
    width:230px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    background-color: #70B0C3;
    border: #3C7D91 1px double;
    box-shadow: #254C58 1px 1px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="title">Your Feedback</div>
</div>
<div id="blank"></div>
<div id="main" style="margin-right: auto; ">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
<h2>SOME TEXT</h2>
</div>
        
<div id="footer">
    BLABLA
</div>
```

Is this what you are looking for ?

refer - [Scrollbar in one div only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513260/scrollbar-in-one-div-only)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking

```html
<html>

<style>
.scroll{
 width:300px;
 height:200px;
 background:red;
 overflow: scroll;
}
</style>

<div class="scroll">
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).However, this code scrolls the whole page and not just one div block. Also, I got stuck in the way I could specify to scroll up and down up to three times and in what positions (otherwise: -300px, -400px and -500px up and down - one after the other).
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the elements scrollable and your function scrolls the whole page because your using window.scroll() instead of yourDiv.scroll()